# onScrollListener no esta funcionando en Fragment de Android

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Estoy tratando de hacer una recyclerviwe con paginación en un fragment, pero cuando quiero aplicar el método addOnScrollListener y ejecutar la aplicación, no funciona.

Puse un Toast para ver si estaba ejecutando el método y solo lo hace cuando se carga, no cuando me desplazo, pongo el método en onCreateView del fragmento y afuera (como es recomendado), nada es nulo, simplemente no hace el onScrollListener.

Aquí está mi código:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_medicamentos, container, false);

    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.scrollableview);


    progressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    getSucPromMeds1(iduser,token,page_number);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);

    return rootView;
}

private final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SCROLLING BITCH",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        pastVisibleItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (dy>0)
        {
            if (isLoading)
            {
                if(totalItemCount>previousTotal)
                {
                    isLoading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                }
            }

            if (!isLoading && (totalItemCount-visibleItemCount)<=(pastVisibleItems+viewThreshold))
            {
                page_number += 20;
                performPagination(iduser,token,page_number);
                isLoading = true;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

En este ejemplo puedes ver como usando onScrolled() puedes detectar scroll hacia la derecha e izquierda,

```
 @Override
    public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
        
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SCROLLING",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (dx > 0) {
            System.out.println("Scroll hacia la derecha.");
        } else if (dx < 0) {
            System.out.println("Scroll hacia la izquierda.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No realiza scroll horizontal.");
        }
   }
```

Con la combinacion de los metodos `onScrollStateChanged()` y `onScrolled()` puedes detectar todos los tipos de movimiento . te sugiero no usar un Toast, imprime en el LogCat los mensajes para que revises el funcionamiento de estos metodos

```
private final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {

        switch (newState) {
            case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                System.out.println("Realiza scroll.");
                break;
            case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
                System.out.println("Asentando Scroll.");
                break;
            case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                System.out.println("No realiza scroll.");
                break;
        }


    }
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
        
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SCROLLING BITCH",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //Movimiento horizontal.
        if (dx > 0) {
            System.out.println("Scroll hacia la derecha.");
        } else if (dx < 0) {
            System.out.println("Scroll hacia la izquierda.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No realiza scroll horizontal.");
        }

        //Movimiento vertical.
        if (dy > 0) {
            System.out.println("Scroll hacia abajo.");
        } else if (dy < 0) {
            System.out.println("Scroll hacia arriba.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No realiza scroll vertical.");
        }


    }
};
```

Comment: Si, eso lo tengo manejado, el problema es que en mi fragment solo me manda a llamar una vez ese metodo, no actua como un listener que se invocacada vez que se hace x accion, sino que solo en el onCreate y de ahi nunca mas

Comment: No uses un toast imprime en el LogCat el funcionamiento, debe funcionar sin problema.

Comment: Pero no lo hace, combine ambas funciones como tu me dijiste, ahora si se ejecuta el onScrolled a raiz de el onScrollStateChanged pero el problema es que dy siempre me da 0, sin importar lo que haga, tendrá que ver con que esta en un fragment?

Comment: Dy es para determinar movimiento vertical en el eje Y, en mi respuesta indico  usar dx y no dy.